# simple_http_dom - how to send request to each url

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have got 16 links in my get-listing.php output and I need to send the request to each URL to get the responses, for which I need to receive the list of elements when send the request to each URL.

```
$base1 = "http://testbox.elementfx.com/get-listing.php";
$html = file_get_html($base1);

$links = $html->find('p[id=links] a');

foreach ($links as $element) 
{
  //open each url in each array
  $urls[] = $url = $element->href;
  $data = file_get_html($url);
}
```

When I use the code as above, it will only send the request to each url to get the response which I have got 9 responses. I should have more than 9 responses.

Can you please tell me how I can send request to every url to get the responses using with simple_http_dom?

Comment: Part of your problem may be that you're violating web standards by having more than one element with the same `id`. Use `class` for that.

Comment: @ceejayoz thank you for your advise, could you please post the code which i will be able to send request to each url to receive the responses?

Comment: Are you looking for every link or for every link which is inside a paragraph that has an id of "links" on it?

Comment: @ChosenWann of course yes I do, I'm looking for every link which has an id of "links" to send request to each url to get the list of elements. On my code it will look for every link which has an id of "links", but it did not send request to every link. When i get the responses for each url, I want to save the variables for the id called `<span id="time1">` and <span id="title1">` to allow me to output them in my main script. Please see the link I have post, hope you will get what I mean?

Comment: Can you please try and do a print_r($links) before the loop then print_r($urls) after the loop?

Comment: @ChosenWann I have got the list of urls when I input the print_r($urls) after the loops, so how I can send request to each url in the loops and how I can save the variables to allow me to get the elements from the tags called `<span id="time1">` and `<span id="title1">`?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is to send a simple request to each of the urls you've already parsed and get a response back, try [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents):

```
foreach ($links as $element)
{
  // This array stack is only necessary if you plan on using it later
  $urls[] = $url = $element->href;

  // $opts and $context are optional for specifying options like method
  $opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
      'method'=>"GET", // "GET" or "POST"
    )
  );
  $context = stream_context_create($opts);

  // Remove context argument if not using options array
  $data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

  // ... Do something with $data
}
```

Your other option is more complex but has more flexibility (depending on the application) is [Curl](https://www.php.net/curl):

```
foreach ($links as $element)
{
  $urls[] = $url = $element->href;

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  // Used for GET request
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, null);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
  // Necessary to return data
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  // ... Do something with $data
}
```

This is scratching the surface of Curl, the documentation on PHP's website (linked above) has more information.

If the data being returned from the urls is HTML, you can pass it through PHP's DomDocument to parse after it has been pulled. Documentation and examples are readily available on PHP's site (I can't post more links right now, sorry).